# SQL: identify duplicate value across non-key attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for best way to identify if there is a duplicate across keyed values.  For instance, if I have t1 called Item, and t2 called SKU, and I want to join them together, and look for an attribute that is only duplicate across that join, and in the SKU table, what is best way to write that SQL?

```
Example: 
Item = A
SKUs = 1, 2, 3
Duplicate Attribute in SKU table = testdupe
```

Assumption is that value testdupe appears in SKU table under A - 1, and A - 3, but not in A - 2.  Expected results would be to show 2 duplicates.  This would then repeat for items B, C, D, etc. and their related SKUs if that join contains an attribute that is duplicated.

Hope that lengthy description is clear and thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.

Comment: `count(*) over (partition by <attribute>)`